# Rewire outlet without drilling through drywall

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have an un-grounded outlet A which is 3 prong (no-no) that is connected with a fairly old (50 years or so) cable to a grounded outlet B. The connecting cable most likely has a flaw (causes breakers to trip) and needs to be replaced.

Is there a way to replace the old cable with a new Romex cable without drilling through drywall? I am thinking that I could (maybe???) fish the new cable using the old cable.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I have found is to break the old box out and remove the staple if possible and possibly use the old wire for a pull but not often will this work. If it won't I  will drill a hole from the attic or crawel space and fish the new romex in. I use an old work box because you can't really secure the box with nails , the old work box hangs onto the sheetrock or plaster. No staples are required behind the finished spaces but they are required in the attic if not run through holes. Have done many old homes this way that were permitted and inspected .
Glow sticks are helpfull (1/8" or larger fiberglass that glows after being in the light) and a coat hanger formed to grab the end of the stick and pull it to the hole and then the wire connected to the end

Answer (score 1):

No. Cable, non-metallic or metallic, needs to be fastened at least every several feet, and routinely makes turns through framing that makes fishing impossible in most circumstances. If the original wiring was anything near code, you can't use old wiring to pull new.

If there is no easy way to work through walls, there are surface wiring methods that can sometimes solve a particular problem. But this is not really a good approach to deal with several runs, and doesn't solve the lack of ground issue.

Comment: Not true when repairing existing installs it is legal to fish wires through the walls without securing the wire.

Comment: I don't dispute it's legal to fish (I do it al the time), but he asked if he could use *existing* wiring to fish, and that stuff don't lend itself to being pulled.

Comment: I have had many successes doing this if I can pull the staple at the box, but it is worth a try easier than fishing, the OP asked if it could be done without drilling through the sheetrock, your answer was no, it can be done by fishing and in some cases by pulling with the old wire, in old work many times it was stapled in the attic and at the box in both it can be done without drilling sheetrock /plaster or the need for surface mounts.